# Write Ping results to a text file

Tags: batch, ping

This should be pretty simple but for some reason, my situation is proving to be a bit tricky...

I want to save the results of a ping to a text file. To do so, I am using the following command in a .bat:

```
ping X.X.X.X >> ping.txt
```

When I run this .bat file, the file created (ping.txt) contains hundreds of rows of the input rather than the output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\XYZ\Desktop>ping X.X.X.X  1>>ping.txt 

C:\Documents and Settings\XYZ\Desktop>ping X.X.X.X  1>>ping.txt 

C:\Documents and Settings\XYZ\Desktop>ping X.X.X.X  1>>ping.txt
```

Anyone have any idea why I'm not getting the results of ping to the text file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your bat file called ping.bat? try renaming it to pong.bat and then run pong.bat!

Comment: wow... just wow - what happened there - the file was named ping.bat; why would this cause a problem? I'm assuming it's because ping.bat/ping.exe causes a conflict?

Comment: When you type `foo` at a command prompt, your windows shell (cmd.exe or whatever) looks in each of the directories in %PATH% for a file named `foo` with any of the filename extensions associated with executable files (.bat .cmd .exe ...) It runs the *first* it finds. Now consider [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Comment: LOL i thought you were trolling until i read the comment above ^